# How to generate Rails migration with Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to generate a migration for my Rails 4 project running within Docker.

What I've tried so far is

```
docker-compose run web rails g migration migration_name
docker-compose exec web rails g migration migration_name
```

Terminal keeps saying me that everything is ok, the migration was successfully created and all. But i don't see migration file in my project.

However if I check the project files in Docker

```
docker-compose exec web bash
ls -l db/migrate/
```

I see that the file is actually there.

I'm on Mac OS X if it could help

Comment: what were you expecting? you are starting a docker container, all created files will be inside container...

Comment: i kind of didn't expect much from the things i did. i just can't successfully run `bundle install` for the project on my system so I had to put the project into Docker environment. I just wanted to ask if it's possible to create a migration file within Docker and get it in your local project folder?

Comment: Yes, you can copy the migration file from the container back to ur host using the command `docker cp <container-name>:<path-to-file-in-container> .`

Comment: Thanks, that would work for now, I was going to do something like this. However it would be great to learn some "right way" to do such things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into making your root app directory a volume on your host machine. [Documentation on volumes.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/)

In your docker-compose.yml, you can add your root volume using:

```
volumes:
  - .:/YOUR-APP-NAME
```

Comment: I had this in my `docker-compose.yml`. But it wasn't set correctly. So I added the volume correctly and it start to work! Thank you. Though your answer isn't actually solution for my problem I guess I should accept it cause it surely points to solution.

Answer (score 0):

When mounting properly it still took a minute or two to show up in my IDE